# Weird site problem with back button

Tags: html

We have a site with a credit card entry form.

The user will enter their information and click submit.  This then goes to a thank you page.

On a ThinkPad laptop running IE 8: If the user clicks the back button (from the thank you page) then it takes them back to the credit card entry.  However, the fields for Name on card, card number and the first line of the address are not there. (ignore for a moment that the page shouldn't be cached..)  I have other machines running IE 8 and 9 that do not exhibit this behavior.

I don't mean that they are empty.  I mean the input fields are flat not there.  The expiration date, city, state and zip input boxes are there.  Just not those listed above.

Any ideas on what could possibly do this?  The fields themselves are always visible and there is absolutely zero code to hide them.

My client says that it happens on other forms in their site as well.  The main site is a joomla application that uses an iFrame to show the forms from my app.

I have no idea on where to even start with this one.

[image]

Comment: We're probably going to need a link.

Comment: Wierd, try deleting the cache. Could it just be that Internet Explorer is setup differently on this machine? try comparing the settings

Comment: @Lenny: At this point I'm wondering if there isn't some type of IE helper that's killing the fields.

Comment: are you using `#hashtags` as part of your form 'history' ?

Comment: I'm closing this question as it is just "too localized" to get any help on.  I can't publish a link for certain reasons and this is only reproducible on one particular machine.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we need a link to troubleshoot. All I can say is likely to be some conflicting css hiding it. Use the element inspector and take a look at all the properties on the fields.

Comment: Accepting because there is no way for anyone to really help on this and I can't delete the post.. ;)